# Where do I get the everyshi.sty file from?

Tags: installing, dtx

I've downloaded and unzipped the ms folder which supposedly has the `everyshi.sty` file; however, to my dismay, the folder has every other file but that one! As a result, I'm failing to run TikZ, since the TeX editor keeps returning an error message that the `everyshi.sty` file is missing.

Can someone please give me a link which could direct me to this file?

Comment: @Jake: This is a [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=install-unpack)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: The distribution of the `.sty` file without the `.dtx` and `.ins` violates its license (the LPPL).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: you are right, sorry. However, notice that just google `everyshi.sty` it is possible to find that page in which the .sty is distributed alone (came back to http://www.liv.ac.uk/~maryrees/posterproduction/).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: So this question could have been answered by googling. `:-(`

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to find it, it is already in the CTAN repository. It's packaged under `ms` --

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ms

if you are using TeX Live manager, just type `tlmgr install ms` on the terminal. Everything related to `everyshi.sty` will be installed, or you can also [manually install](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system) the zipped 'ms' package that you have already downloaded.

Answer (score 5):

You should not have to install packages like everyshi by yourself; your TeX installation most likely has a way to install packages. Sadly you don't tell us anything about your situation (which TeX distribution on what OS?).

Also this is a [FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-install-unpack): LaTeX packages are typically unpacked by running a `.ins` file through LaTeX: this will create files suitable for LaTeX (like `.sty`) from a `.dtx`.